# A hot observable that switches what it emits depending on system state (with code sample)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm just starting with Reactive programming (rx, C#). I'm trying to make a hot observable that switches its behavior depending on the current system state. Here are the textual description of what I'm trying to achieve, the state diagram to simplify understanding what it should do and the "close to working" code sample that can be run to interactively test the code.

Any help or directions are highly appreciated, thank you!

---

### Textual description

Make a hot observable that:

- emits nothing in the initial state
- when RepeatingMessage is set, emits the message at specified periods
- when RepeatingMessage is unset, stops emiting repeating messages
- when a user message arrives, emits the user message and then waits for userMessage.Cooldown time for another user message to arrive without emitting repeating message.
- after cooldown has passed either returns to emitting the repeating message or returns to the "emit nothing" state.

---

### State diagram

### [image]

### Fully working code following advice by Shlomo

Thanks for the effort, this helped me a lot with understanding! I've changed the code following the logic, tried to make it more readable, it now fully works!
Run the program, pressing 'r' switches the repeating message on/off, pressing 'x' terminates the program, pressing any other key sends a user-message and triggers a 2 second cooldown during which only user messages are accepted and repeating messages are not broadcast.

```
namespace Testing
{
    #region SupportClasses

    class RepeatMsgChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public RepeatMsgChangedEventArgs(RepeatMsg repeatMsgNew, RepeatMsg repeatMsgOld)
        {
            RepeatMsgNew = repeatMsgNew;
            RepeatMsgOld = repeatMsgOld;
        }

        public RepeatMsg RepeatMsgNew { get; }
        public RepeatMsg RepeatMsgOld { get; }
    }

    class UserMsgArrivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public UserMsgArrivedEventArgs(UserMessage userMessage)
        {
            UserMessage = userMessage;
        }

        public UserMessage UserMessage { get; }
    }

    class RepeatMsg
    {
        public static readonly RepeatMsg None = new RepeatMsg {Period = TimeSpan.MaxValue, Message = ""};

        /// <summary> I.e. (1 / frequency), delay till the next repeating event is fired.</summary>
        public TimeSpan Period { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
        public string Message { get; set; } = "repeating-message";
    }

    class UserMessage
    {
        public static readonly UserMessage None = new UserMessage {Cooldown = TimeSpan.Zero, Message = ""};

        /// <summary> How much time to wait for another UserEvent before starting emitting RepeatingEvent again.</summary>
        public TimeSpan Cooldown { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        public string Message { get; set; } = "user-message";
    }

    #endregion

    class Program
    {

        // Repeating message can be set and unset.
        // These actions start/stop the timer that triggers hot observable streamRepeat
        private RepeatMsg _repeatMsg = RepeatMsg.None;
        private RepeatMsg RepeatMsg
        {
            get => _repeatMsg;
            set
            {
                // when repeating message is set/unset, start/stop the timer
                // emitting repeating msg events
                if (_repeatMsg == value) return;
                RepeatMsg old = _repeatMsg;
                _repeatMsg = value;
                RepeatMsgChanged?.Invoke(this, new RepeatMsgChangedEventArgs(value, old));
            }
        }

        // streamRepeat is triggered by this event.
        public event EventHandler<RepeatMsgChangedEventArgs> RepeatMsgChanged;

        // streamUser is triggered by this event. 
        public event EventHandler<UserMsgArrivedEventArgs> UserMsgArrived;


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            p.SetUpRx();                // set up the observables
            p.KeyboardControlLoop();    // start while loop listenig to keyboard keys, press 'x' to exit
        }

        private void SetUpRx()
        {
            IObservable<RepeatMsg> streamRepeat = Observable
                .FromEventPattern<RepeatMsgChangedEventArgs>(h => RepeatMsgChanged += h, h => RepeatMsgChanged -= h)
                .Select(args => args.EventArgs.RepeatMsgNew);

            IObservable<UserMessage> streamUser = Observable
                .FromEventPattern<UserMsgArrivedEventArgs>(h => UserMsgArrived += h, h => UserMsgArrived -= h)
                .Select(e => e.EventArgs.UserMessage);

            IObservable<string> streamFinal = streamRepeat
                .Select(rm => rm == RepeatMsg.None
                    ? Observable.Never<string>()
                    : Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, rm.Period).Select(_ => rm.Message)
                )
                .Switch()
                .Publish(repeatStream => streamUser
                    .Select(um => Observable.Empty<string>()
                        .Delay(um.Cooldown)
                        .StartWith(um.Message)
                        .Concat(repeatStream)
                    )
                    .StartWith(repeatStream)
                    .Switch()
                );

            streamFinal.Subscribe(message => Log(message));
        }

        private void KeyboardControlLoop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press:\n" +
                              "    'x' key to exit\n" +
                              "    'r' key to switch repeating on/off\n" +
                              "    any other key to send it as a user message");

            char c = char.MaxValue;
            while (c != 'x')
            {
                var consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
                c = consoleKeyInfo.KeyChar;
                switch (c)
                {
                    case 'x':
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        if (RepeatMsg == null || RepeatMsg == RepeatMsg.None)
                        {
                            RepeatMsg = new RepeatMsg
                            {
                                Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0),
                                Message = $"New repeat msg \"{c}\" set @{DateTime.Now:O}"
                            };
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            RepeatMsg = RepeatMsg.None;
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        // any other key pressed, rise UserMessageArrived event
                        var cooldown = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0);
                        var msg = new UserMessage
                        {
                            Cooldown = cooldown,
                            Message = $"User message: key pressed = '{c}', timeout = {cooldown.TotalSeconds:F2}s"
                        };
                        UserMsgArrived?.Invoke(this, new UserMsgArrivedEventArgs(msg));
                        break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping..");
        }

        private static void Log(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"@{DateTime.Now:O}: {message}");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Originally posted test code (moved to the bottom)

The `// TODO:` comments mark places where something needs to be added.
The code will work, if you for example assign `eventLoop = emitRepeatingMessage` and set the `RepeatingMessage` to something.

```
class Program
{
    private RepeatingMessage _repeatingMessage;
    public RepeatingMessage RepeatingMessage
    {
        get => _repeatingMessage;
        set
        {
            _repeatingMessage = value;
            RepeatingEventChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler RepeatingEventChanged;

    public event EventHandler<UserEventArgs> UserMessageArrived; 


    public void Run()
    {
        Log("Main thread started");

        // These are some initial attempts
        var doNothing = Observable
            .Never<string>();
        var emitRepeatingMessage = Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, _repeatingMessage.Period)
            .Select(l => _repeatingMessage.Message);
        var emitUserMessage = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<UserEventArgs>(h => UserMessageArrived += h, h => UserMessageArrived -= h)
            .Select(e => e.EventArgs.UserMessage); // this is not complete, cooldown needs to be added

        IObservable<string> eventLoop = // TODO: Some magic here 
        eventLoop.Subscribe(message => Log(message));
        Log("Main thread done");


        char c = char.MaxValue;
        while (c != 'x')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press:\n" +
                              "    'x' key to exit\n" +
                              "    'r' key to switch repeating on/off\n" +
                              "    any other key to send it as a user message");
            c = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
            switch (c)
            {
                case 'x':
                    // TODO: stop eventLoop somehow?
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    // TODO: switch eventLoop to messagesRepeat?
                    break;
                default:
                    var msg = new UserMessage()
                    {
                        Cooldown = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0),
                        Message = $"User message: key char = '{c}'"
                    };
                    UserMessageArrived?.Invoke(this, new UserEventArgs(msg));
                    break;
            }                
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Any key pressed, stopping...");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();
    }

    private static void Log(string message) {
        Console.WriteLine($"@{DateTime.Now:O}: {message}");        
    }
}

class UserEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public UserMessage UserMessage { get; }

    public UserEventArgs(UserMessage userMessage)
    {
        UserMessage = userMessage;
    }
}

interface IMessage
{
    string Message();
}

class RepeatingMessage : IMessage
{
    /// <summary> I.e. (1 / frequency), delay till the next repeating event is fired.</summary>
    public TimeSpan Period { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
    public string Message { get; set; } = "repeating-message";
    string IMessage.Message()
    {
        return Message;
    }
}

class UserMessage : IMessage
{
    /// <summary> How much time to wait for another UserEvent before starting emitting RepeatingEvent again.</summary>
    public TimeSpan Cooldown { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    public string Message { get; set; } = "user-message";
    string IMessage.Message()
    {
        return Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to follow your code, hopefully this helps. I'm assuming a null `RepeatingMessage` is the equivalent of 'unset'. I think best practice is to NOT propagate nulls, rather using a special value, but it will work. I'm also assuming you can re-set a repeating message even if one is already set:

```
IObservable<RepeatingMessage> repeatingMessages; //Fill in
IObservable<UserMessage> userMessages;  //Fill in, best guess is:
//  IObservable<UserMessage> userMessages = Observable.FromEventPattern<UserEventArgs>(
//          h => UserMessageArrived += h, 
//          h => UserMessageArrived -= h
//      )
//      .Select(e => e.EventArgs.UserMessage);

var final = repeatingMessages
    .Select(rm => rm == null
        ? Observable.Never<string>()
        : Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, rm.Period).Select(_ => rm.Message)
    )
    .Switch()
    .Publish(_repeatStream => userMessages
        .Select(um => Observable.Empty<string>()
            .Delay(um.Cooldown)
            .StartWith(um.Message)
            .Concat(_repeatStream)
        )
        .StartWith(_repeatStream)
        .Switch()
    );
```

**Explanation:**

It's best to think of these things as read-only streams that get built up bit by bit. We want to avoid using mutable-state. We start with two streams; A `userMessages` stream and a `repeatingMessages` stream:

```
repeatingMessages: -------RM1------(null)----RM2------
userMessages     : --(UM1,8)-(UM2,5)---(UM3,3)--------
```

The user messages we want to imagine as a message followed by a variable cooldown period. However, the cooldown can be interrupted by another user message. In this marble diagram, the c's in `userComb` represent cooldown time. They mean nothing to UserMessages, they're only used when combined with repeatingMessages:

```
userMessages     : --(UM1,8)-(UM2,5)---(UM3,3)--------
  UM1            :   *--------|
  UM2            :           *-----|
  UM3            :                     *---|
userComb         : --UM1cccccUM2ccc----UM3c-----------
```

The code for userComb looks like this:

```
var userComb = userMessages
    .Select(um => Observable.Empty<string>()
        .Delay(um.Cooldown)
        .StartWith(um.Message)
    )
    .Switch();
```

The repeating messages we want to view as a switchable series of repeating messages with varying repeating times:

```
repeatingMessages: -------RM1------(null)----RM2------
repeatingComb    : -------RM1-RM1-RM1--------RM2---RM2
```

The code for repeatingComb would look like this:

```
var repeatingComb = repeatingMessages
    .Select(rm => rm == null
        ? Observable.Never<string>()
        : Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, rm.Period).Select(_ => rm.Message)
    )
    .Switch();
```

Now, let's put it all together:

```
repeatingMessages: -------RM1------(null)----RM2------
userMessages     : --(UM1,8)-(UM2,5)---(UM3,3)--------
repeatingComb    : -------RM1-RM1-RM1--------RM2---RM2
userComb         : --UM1cccccUM2ccc----UM3c-----------
desired          : --UM1-----UM2-------UM3---RM2---RM2
```

Desired basically is `userComb` + `repeatingComb` except where userComb has c's. The way we can achieve this is to always switch to the latest user stream (which includes the cooldown period), then when the cooldown period has ended, switch back to the `repeatingComb` stream (hence adding the `.Concat(_repeatStream)` to the previously shown `userComb`.

---

**EDIT**

I forgot that `repeatingMessages` can trigger before `userMessages`, I added a `.StartWith(_repeatStream)` which should handle that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this greatly helped me with thinking about streams! This hands-on excercise looks to be more useful than reading tutorials :) The updated code almost works, if you have time, could you please help me figure out where the last culprit is. If not, then not, you already helped me out enough! Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure. Missed that case. Updated code (see additional `.StartWith`). Try again?

Comment: Works like a charm!